# append dataframes of different size in same csv file (R)

Tags: r, csv, merge, append, sink

Wasn't able to find a solution to this.
I have a bunch of dataframes (subsets of bigger dataframes), like that.

```
a     b    c
3,4  good  HJJR
```

and

```
cod      x   c     utc    country
jhh34s   5  HJJR    +1     Poland
jhh22d   0  JJHE    +1     Poland
```

And I would simply like to sink them in a single csv file like so:

```
a     b    c
3,4  good  HJJR

cod      x   c     utc    country
jhh34s   5  HJJR    +1     Poland
jhh22d   0  JJHE    +1     Poland
```

Is this even possible? It's important to end up with a csv file though. And obviously the dfs have different number of rows and columns.
Thank you

Comment: `write.csv` and friends are really designed for outputting tabular data. If reading back into R, `save` is the way to go. for text based storage of multiple objects, take a look at `dump`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really an easy way to do exactly what you want.
But one hacky way is to use the `sink()` function to redirect all console output to a file.

```
df1 <- data.frame( A= c(1,2,3,4), B= c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
df2 <- data.frame( A= c(1,2,3))

# start redirecting output
sink(file = "file1.csv")
df1
df2
# close the file
sink()
```

This of course will not give you a native csv, but you could then open and write the file again.

```
file2 <- read.table(file = "file1.csv", sep = " ", fill = TRUE)
write.csv(file2 ,file= "file2.csv")
```